# Is it possible to have JMS queue wait until it has received the acknowledgement of a message before dispatching the next message

Tags: java, jms, openmq

I have setup a JMS queue that is fed by a single producer, and consumed by 8 different consumers.

I would like to configure my queue/broker so that one message being delivered to a consumer blocks the queue until the consumer is done processing the message. During the processing of this first message, the following messages may not be delivered to another consumer. It doesn't matter which consumer processes which message, and it is acceptable for the same consumer to consume many messages in a row as long as when it dies another consumer is able to pick up the rest of the unprocessed messages.

In order to do this, I have configured all of my consumers to use the `CLIENT` acknowledgement mode, and I have coded them so that `message.acknowledge()` is called only at the end of the message processing.

My understanding was that this should be sufficient to satisfy my requirements.

However I am apparently wrong, because it looks like my brojer (OpenMQ) is delivering the messages to consumers as fast as possible, without waiting for the consumer acknowledgement. As a result, I get multiple messages processed in parallel, one for each consumer.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

As a workaround, I figure I could create a durable subscription with a fixed client ID shared between all my consumers. It would probably work by only allowing one consumer to even connect to the broker, but I can't shake the feeling that this is a rather ugly workaround.

Does anyone have an idea of how I should configure my Broker and/or my Client to make this possible?

Comment: That's not the way asynch processing works.  Shouldn't this be a topic instead of a queue if you have multiple consumers of the same message?

Comment: That's because I don't want it to be asynchronous. In my case, I use the JMS queue to take advantage of some of its properties: Guaranteed delivery, and message ordering (and I'm having trouble with the second). I do not intend to have multiple concurrent consumers, I just need one. That's why I'm using a queue rather than a topic. 

I don't have much experience with JMS, so please tell me if I'm not making sense.

Comment: You're using queues incorrectly, then.  Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Really? Then what am I supposed to do to have a Queue/Topic that behaves like the normal definition of a FIFO queue where a message is only taken out of the FIFO queue when it has been successfully processed?

Comment: Each of the consumers, taking turns in a single queue listener, would do what you need.  You can put each step in the same try/catch block so the later processors can know if an earlier one had an issue.  They really are synchronous if I understand you correctly.  Making each processor a separate queue listener overcomplicates the communication between them.

Comment: That is the behavior I would like, indeed. But in this case, each consumer is in a different process on a different physical machine. All consumers are identical, and it really doesn't matter which consumer consumes which message. The only important thing is that messages are processed only once, and in the same order as they were inserted into the FIFO Queue.

Comment: I think my solution accomplishes that: a single JMS listener to take the message off the queue and multiple processors inside it, operating on the request in the sequence you establish by their order.  Easy.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I implement a single JMS listener to take the message off the queue if my processors are on different JVM instances and different physical machines? Isn't a JMS listener instance confined to a single JVM?

Comment: At this stage, it look like the `JMSXGroupId` attribute could do what I need, but I'm not sure whether it is implemented by OpenMQ.

Comment: Your processors won't be on different JMS listeners: You'll encapsulate the behavior in objects that live inside the single listener that you should have.  You're too wedded to your original, bad idea.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this?

Comment: @JackWhipnert: I ended going for a different solution. But if my memory is correct, the `JMSXGroupId` attribute is the answer. However it is not supported by OpenMQ. It is supported by ActiveMQ though.